# Cannot resolve class com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView

Tags: java, android, admob, ads, native-ads

i am trying admobe native ads in app and getting this error on
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'`

but working fine on
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'`

my gradle file is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 32

defaultConfig {

        applicationId "xxx-xxx-xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
     
    buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'
}
dependencies {
.....
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
// implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
........
}
```

**here is the picture of my code error in XML file**

[error in xml file implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Szm.png)

i tried implementation `'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.6.0'` and it is working fine in this dependency but it giving error in `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'`

i want to upade my dependency what will be the soultion for this error

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 33

defaultConfig {

        applicationId "xxx-xxx-xxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
.....
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.5.0'
// implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.5.0'
........
}
```

Update `compileSdkVersion` support to `33`